# Why is the spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener() not getting executed?

Tags: java, android, spinner

**UPDATE:**
I have found a work around that isn't necessarily the solution, but has solved my problem. To my interpretation, I think the use of online database causes a little delay or something that when the `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener()` is set the list passed to the adapter is empty. So to counter that, I set the listener in the `OnDataChange()` method of firebase (which was fetching the data from database and creating the list). After that it worked fine.

**Original Question**

I have a simple spinner inside a layout in xml, and I have a query that creates a String type array of the items I want to show in the spinner. The list is being created and the spinner shows the items. But when I call the `setOnItemSelectedListener()` on it, it is not getting executed.

This is the xml:

```
           <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    >

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner_category_name_add_expense"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
```

There are more widgets around it, I don't know if that matters.

This is the java file:

```
public class AddExpense extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner_category_name_add_expense;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    String userKey, userName, selected_cat;
    DatabaseReference dbref;
    ArrayList<String> categoryModelArrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_expense);
        fetchSharedPreferences();
        categoryModelArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        spinner_category_name_add_expense = findViewById(R.id.spinner_category_name_add_expense);
        createCategoryList();
        addCategoriesToSpinner();
        spinner_category_name_add_expense.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 
            AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(AddExpense.this, "Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // not executing this 
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                Toast.makeText(AddExpense.this, "Not Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // nor this
            }
        });        
    
}

    
    }


    private void fetchSharedPreferences() {
        sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("shared_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        userKey = sharedPreferences.getString("user_key", null);
        
    }

// gets the data from firebase database, works as the ArrayList is populated
    public void createCategoryList() {
        String currentUserCategoriesPath = "AssignmentUsers/" + userKey + "/userCategories";
        dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(currentUserCategoriesPath);
        dbref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int i = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String categoryModel = snapshot.getKey();
                    categoryModelArrayList.add(categoryModel);
                    Log.d("firebase", String.valueOf(categoryModelArrayList.get(i)));
                    i++;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("firebase", "Error");
            }
        });


    }

    public void addCategoriesToSpinner() {
        spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                categoryModelArrayList
        );

        spinner_category_name_add_expense.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Comment: `But when I call the setOnItemSelectedListener()` What do you mean? That statement sets a listener. If the listener is called depends on the user clicking on it.

Comment: I mean that if I set the listener, shouldn't the ` onItemSelected() ` method get executed when I select something from the spinner?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: But it isn't. I have tried quite a lot of things but can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.